# Vue 3 - Independent event propagation on slots

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

today I've got a tricky question about Vue concerning slots and event propagation. [**Here is a codesample**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-uyyjtc?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/OrderCancellationPage.vue)

Some background information: I've got an order, which has n order positions. Those orders and its positions are displayed at different pages. To achieve a consistent UI, I created vue components for `Order.vue` and `Position.vue`. Those components do not contain any business logic and are only responsible for consistent styles in my app.

Furthermore, I've got a order detail view, which displays information of my order with its positions.
[image]

Additionally, I've got another view, where the same information is displayed AND it should be possible to select some order/positions for cancellation.

[image]

Data is contained in the page component and passed as props to the order/position. For the cancellation page, I'm passing the checkbox component within slots:

```
// OrderCancellationPage.vue
<Order v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id" :id="order.id" :positions="order.positions">
  <InvoiceCancellationCheckbox :order-id="order.id" @isCancelled="onCancelledEvent($event)" />
</Order>
```

```
// Order.vue
<div>
  <h3>Order: # {{ id }}</h3>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
<OrderPosition
  v-for="position in positions"
  :key="position.posIndex"
  :pos-index="position.posIndex"
>
  <InvoiceCancellationCheckbox :orderId="id" :posIndex="position.posIndex"       @isCancelled="$emit('isCancelled', $event)"/> //propagate the event to order
</OrderPosition>
```

```
// OrderPosition.vue
<div>
  <span>Position {{ posIndex }}</span>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

**I want to achieve, that my order/positions components do not contain any logic for the cancellation.** For this reason, the `InvoiceCancellationCheckbox` is emitting an event if it has been checked. `Order` and `Position` are listening on this event with `@isCancelled=...`, which has been declared inside my slot component. In the end, the `OrderCancellationPage` should listen on all of those events and store the selected orders with its positions.

**The problem:** I'm getting this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners (isCancelled) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option. 
  at <Order key="2021-9064-9333-9803" id="2021-9064-9333-9803" positions=
```

I could solve this warning, if i would add `emits: ['isCancelled']` to `Order`. However, than Order is coupled with the cancellation checkbox, which i do not want. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Would a custom v-model be something you'd consider "non-coupled" for your purpose? I'm using re-usable components that might be used in various different places without a strict context, and I'm using a custom v-model which makes use of prop `modelValue` and a generic emit `emits: ['update:modelValue']` which will be emitted on change of the checkbox, and whenever I need it in my parent components, I can watch the modelled value

Comment: Thanks this worked so far! Same functionality, without this warning and better understandable code.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad the hint alone helped you find a suitable approach

Comment: Maybe you want to post the solution as an answer for other coming across this page

Comment: I posted my solution, however its not working on Stackblitz but on my local machine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Seems like the example is not working on stackblitz, however its working on a local machine. I do not see any errors in this code...

---

`v-model` saved the day.

I forked the old code with the solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-t6ekts

Basically its about using `v-model` for the checkbox:

```
<template>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" :id="id" v-model="modelValue" />
    <label :for="id">Select for cancellation</label>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  props: {
    modelValue: Boolean,
    orderId: String,
    posIndex: Number
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  watch: {
    modelValue() {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.modelValue);
    },
  },
```

and passing it as a slot:

```
<Order v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id" :id="order.id" :order="order">
  <CancellationCheckbox :order-id="order.id" v-model="order.isCancelled"/>
</Order>
```

```
<OrderPosition v-for="position in order.positions" :key="position.posIndex" :position="position">
  <CancellationCheckbox :orderId="order.id" :posIndex="position.posIndex" v-model="position.isCancelled"/>
</OrderPosition>
```

Comment: Actually the fail on Website is giving you critical hints. I [forked your version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-9a5avv?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FOrder.vue). In your `CancellationCheckbox` you used your modelValue for a v-model as well. But you should restrain from mutating a prop, this can break in production or introduce strange cross-change due to inherited reactivity. I introduced a new datapoint for the Checkbox and bind it to the prop modelValue (which can be omitted since it's a vue default emit/prop). Then watch the boundValue and `emit('update:modelValue')` on it's change

Comment: I don't think its right to omit the declaration of `modelValue` as a property. Using inspector of vue developer tools, I can see that `modelValue` is an attribute and not a property. 

In my advanced usecase (selecting all positions, if the order is selected) i need to declare it as a property, otherwise watching updates on `modelValue` are not recognized.
Have a look at my [updated version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-4uacx5).

Comment: In this case, you are right.